# Powershell - get content between 2 strings in multiple lines

Tags: regex, powershell

I have file 1.wpl:

```
<?wpl version="1.0"?>
<smil>
    <head>
        <meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Windows Media Player -- 12.0.22621.1"/>
        <meta name="ItemCount" content="2"/>
        <title>Untitled playlist</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <seq>
            <media src="C:\Users\user\Downloads\Katzianerova vojna.mp3"/>
            <media src="C:\Users\user\Downloads\Rat i mir u povijesti III- dio.mp3"/>
        </seq>
    </body>
</smil>
```

I want to get content between `<seq>` and `</seq>` in multiple lines:

**Desired output:**

```
<media src="C:\Users\user\Downloads\Katzianerova vojna.mp3"/>
<media src="C:\Users\user\Downloads\Rat i mir u povijesti III- dio.mp3"/>
```

Have this code which gives me output in single line:

```
$fileName = "C:\Users\user\Music\Playlists\1.wpl"
 #Get content from file
$file = Get-Content $fileName
   
#Regex pattern to compare two strings
$pattern = "<seq>(.*?)</seq>"

#Perform the opperation
$results = [regex]::Match($file,$pattern).Groups[1].Value -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

return $results
```

**Actual output:**

```
 <media src="C:\Users\user\Downloads\Katzianerova vojna.mp3"/>             <media src="C:\Users\user\Downloads\Rat i mir u povijesti III- dio.m
p3"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is literally no reason to use regex when what you have is valid XML:

```bash
($xml = [xml]::new()).Load('C:\Users\user\Music\Playlists\1.wpl')
$xml.SelectNodes('smil/body/seq/media') | ForEach-Object OuterXml

# Outputs:
# <media src="C:\Users\user\Downloads\Katzianerova vojna.mp3" />
# <media src="C:\Users\user\Downloads\Rat i mir u povijesti III- dio.mp3" />
```

Or using wildcard in the XPath:

```bash
($xml = [xml]::new()).Load('C:\Users\user\Music\Playlists\1.wpl')
$xml.SelectNodes("//seq/*") | ForEach-Object OuterXml
```

Comment: works, but how to adjust above script to get values between `<media src=` and `/>`

Comment: @overflowed `$xml.SelectNodes("//seq/*").src` like that

Comment: getting nothing

Comment: @overflowed https://i.imgur.com/KBSDdtf.png not sure what to tell. works fine for me

Comment: ah, yes!, getting "column" named src

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a "switch"

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\user\Music\Playlists\1.wpl" |
    ForEach-Object {
        switch -Regex ($_) {
            '\<seq\>$' {
                $break = 1
            }
            '\<\/seq\>$' {
                $break = 0
            }
            default {
                if ($break -eq 1) {
                    $_ -replace '^\s+'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

found solution:

```
$fileContent = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\user\Music\Playlists\1.wpl" -Raw
$regexPattern = "(?s)<seq>(.*?)</seq>"
$matches = [regex]::Match($fileContent, $regexPattern)

if ($matches.Success) {
    $seqContent = $matches.Groups[1].Value
    $lines = $seqContent -split "`n"
    $output = ($lines | Where-Object { $_.Trim() -ne '' }) -join "`n"
    Write-Output $output
} else {
    Write-Output "No <seq> content found in the file."
}
```